# A different form of sort method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In using the sort method I can replace the return statement of `return a - b` to `return a > b` and get the same result,why?
Codes below:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
  return a > b;
}
```

and seems it works just like

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
  return a - b;
}
```

Comment: a > b will give true/false where a-b will give +/- which is taken as true/false by javascript compiler

Comment: the first one takes too many steps than the second

Comment: sort's callback needs to return one of three values, smaller than 0, 0 or greater than 0. if you take just true/false, you made the sorting longer, or produces a missorted array, depending on the implementation.

Comment: Type coercion + that's how [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works.

Comment: @ABUdhay If `a = 2` and `b = 5`, `a - b = -3` which is *truthy*: only `0` is *falsy*.

Comment: @NinaScholz So I better not use it,the first one?

Comment: They aren't equal. For example an array with  integers. The first will sort them by string value, so 785 will appear before 90. The second one will sort by int value, so 90 will be smaller than 785. As you can read below the sort function should return a number.

Comment: @HaoZonggang the first version doesn't work anymore in ES6. I expanded my answer explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects three possible results:

- If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than
  b, i.e. a comes first.
- If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a
  and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect
  to all different elements.
- If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than
  0, sort b to a lower index than a.

In your case, the first example returns `true` or `false`, but `Array.sort()` expects a number, so it converts the true/false to a number, where true = 1, false = 0.

Anyway in ES6 your first snippet doesn't work (also it works now, but can give you unexpected results as explained in comments to your question), [as described here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort), because:

> Calling comparefn(a,b) always returns the same value v when given a
>   specific pair of values a and b as its two arguments. Furthermore,
>   Type(v) is Number, and v is not NaN.

the return type of your first snippet is `boolean`.

Anyway, in older versions of ES, it works because chapter **15.4.4.5** of [specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) says

> A function is a consistent comparison function for a set of values if (a) for any two of those values
>   (possibly the same value) considered as an ordered pair, it always returns the same value when given that
>   pair of values as its two arguments, and the result of applying ToNumber to this value is not NaN;

```js
console.log(Number(true))
console.log(Number(false))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort function expects lower than 0, 0 or grater than 0 number when comparing two elements.

`< 0` - first element has priority
`= 0` - both elements has same priority
`> 0` - second element has priority

So `a - b` will return correct values range while `a > b` will return only `0` and `1` leading to missing comparison result in sorting and can have negative results with some data sets.